# Have tcp connection or send Http request forcibly on ethernet instead of wifi

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, server

I'm developing application for a special android device which has ethernet and wifi connection at same time. i use wifi for internet connection and ethernet for local connection to a server. i can connect to local server via tcp or webservice ( using google volley library). my problem is all connection requests go through wifi by default , so i can't send request to local server. how can i force android to send requests through ethernet connection? i don't want to lose my wifi connectivity though.

ps , i can ping my local server using Termux , so android device and server are successfully connected.

EDIT : 
here's my code to connect my local server:

```
    public void fetchdata() {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    ....

                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    ....
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

    };

    queue.add(getRequest);


}
```

Comment: You can specify the outgoing interface to use. How to do depends on your code. Edit your question and post the relevant code.

Comment: The interface which its used depends on the routing. If the default route is through wifi and no more specific route to the target using ethernet exists, then wifi will be used.

Comment: @robert i don't have access to my code right now i'll post it few hours later, until then may you explain how to change the interface generally? i'm using volley to send request without any addition or custom settings.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich how can i see or change the default route? and i didn't get "no more specific route to the target using ethernet exists". android device and the target server are connected via ethernet cable.

Comment: @MohsenEinhesari: in the typical setup the device gets its IP address automatically using DHCP and this also sets the router. If you get two IP addresses within the same subnet or when a default route is announced for both interfaces then you should consider your setup broken. The proper way to announce a specific route to the device/net which should be used by ethernet within DHCP, i.e, the setup on your DHCP server and less on your Android device counts.

Comment: @robert I posted my code.

Comment: It seems like Google Volley does not support to set the outgoing interface.

Comment: @Robert there's no obligation to use Google Volley. what is your suggestion? which library can i use to set outgoing interface?

Comment: The recent versions of Apache HTTP Client supports it, but I am not sure if this also applies to the old version that was available on Android. You may want to use a repackaged version to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @Robert ok i'll try it, thanks